# How do I convert a number to a string in the same format as the input in python?

Tags: python

Consider the following lines:

```
a = 5e7
print(str(a))
```

I get 50000000.0 instead of 5e7 itself, can I do this using str command itself ?

Comment: There's no way to know what format the input was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing the format of the original input, since only the *type* and *value* are remembered during parsing.

However, if you are looking for how to display a number in exponential form, use the `e` format specifier, like this:

```
a = 5e7
print("{:0.0e}".format(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are able to write in another way too.
I prefer using this method because it is clearer.

```
a = 5e7
print(f"{a:0.0e}")
```

However if you have more than one int or float to be used in a sentence, you can write it something like this.

```
print("{a:0.0e} ... {a:0.0e}".format(a = 5e7))
```

The code above will give u 2 var "a"

For more codes please check

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Hopefully this will help u.